# Help with SQL INNER JOIN statement

Tags: sql, pervasive

I have 2 tables , one showing me customer addresses and one other table showing all the order data.  i would like to query the two tables using a JOIN so that i can get a result set shwoing me all the email addresses for customers that have not ordered in the last year.

so far i have this , but my inner join is not working, if you may help:

```
SELECT SHH.CUST_NO,ADR.EMAIL  

FROM SALES_HISTORY_HEADER SHH,ADDRESS ADR

INNER JOIN ADR ON
SHH.CUST_NO = ADR.CUST_NO  


GROUP BY SHH.CUST_NO 
HAVING Max(SHH.INVOICE_DATE) < '20100728'
```

Comment: "my inner join is not working" is not a full description, also, what dbms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were mixing join styles. If you're going to use explicit joins (and you should) then you specify the second table on the JOIN rather than listing all the tables in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT SHH.CUST_NO,ADR.EMAIL  
    FROM SALES_HISTORY_HEADER SHH
        INNER JOIN ADDRESS ADR 
            ON SHH.CUST_NO = ADR.CUST_NO  
    GROUP BY SHH.CUST_NO, ADR.EMAIL
    HAVING Max(SHH.INVOICE_DATE) < '20100728'
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the help, but Im getting an error stating "COLUMN INVALID: Must be a group by column: EMAIL in SELECT LIST"

Comment: @seb then you need to add ADR.EMAIL to your GROUP By statement

Comment: @seb: Added `ADR.EMAIL` to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, thank you, you are right, I didn't notice that

Comment: one last question , do you guys think this is the most efficient way to write this statement? its been running a few minutes now , is there a faster way to extract this data? thanks!

Comment: @seb: What RDBMS and which version are you using?

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli Its called PERVASIVE v10.30